# $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that |$f(x) - f(y)$| $\leq c{|x - y|}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such  that |$f(x) - f(y)$| $\leq c{|x - y|}^k$ where  $c \geq 0$ and $k$  greater  than 1. Show  that  $f$  is  a  constant  function. I  notice  that  $f$  is  continuous.

Comment: Is it assumed $f$ is continuous, or do you mean you have somehow proved that?

Comment: It  is  not  assumed.

Comment: @JackyChong That function does not fulfill the inequality (note $k>1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\neq y$ you get
$$
\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq C|x-y|^{k-1}.
$$
Observe that $k-1>0$, let $y\to x$.